# Where do I find the latest ansible error log

Tags: ansible

I used an ansible script to bring a server configuration up. I was running the script from inside the server and doing everything at the localhost inventory.

Now the ssh connection I had to the server closed and I cannot find the log file. Where is the standard log path for this? Under /var/log there is no ansible file.

I am running the script again, and I expect the error to come again, but this is not a great solution since the script takes a few hours to run to the error point.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ansible doesn't create its own logs by default - you have to tell it to do so, using an `ansible.cfg` file. Ansible does do *some* logging to syslog by default:

> Note that ansible will, without this setting, record module arguments
> called to the syslog of *managed* machines.

So that'll log module args to the syslog *of the machines you're managing*.

To switch on *full* logging on your control machine, you can create an `ansible.cfg` file that looks like this:

```
[defaults]
log_path = ./ansible.log
```

Then save it somewhere ansible will look for it. Ansible checks these locations for `ansible.cfg` files, in this order:

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

An alternative option is to set the `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH` environment variable, to the path you want to log to—it's equivalent to setting the `log_path` option in the `ansible.cfg` file.

See here for more information: http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html

Comment: It is also possible to set the environment variable [ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/a9d5bf717c200126c46433de1a833f2dd34397f6/lib/ansible/constants.py#L184)

Answer (score 3):

Have a rummage around in your system's syslog file location.  That's where it usually ends up for me (Ubuntu 12.04).

Failing that, you might want to run `ansible-playbook -vvvv $args` to turn on some debug logging, then `tee` it to a file.